# What is autopoint?

Tags: apt

I need to install autopoint. I tried by using

```
sudo apt-get install autopoint
```

But it says `E: Unable to locate package autopoint`. I am new to Ubuntu, I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx.

Comment: Why are you installing it in first place?

Comment: `autopoint` isn't available for Ubuntu 10.04, you need at least Ubuntu 12.04. As Ubuntu 10.04 isn't supported for desktop use any more you likely should upgrade to 12.04 or later anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `autopoint` program is part of [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), a set of tools for translating programs into different languages.

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and later, it can be installed with

```
apt-get install autopoint
```

as you rightly assumed. In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, however, the `autopoint` program was part of a monolithic `gettext` package. So you should

```
apt-get install gettext
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

To find where a package is, do this (example in 14.04).

1. Install `apt-file`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-file 
   sudo apt-file update
   ```
2. Wait :-)
3. search for a file:

   ```
   apt-file search autopoint
   ```
4. Results:

   ```
   autopoint: /usr/bin/autopoint
   autopoint: /usr/share/doc/autopoint/changelog.Debian.gz
   autopoint: /usr/share/doc/autopoint/copyright
   autopoint: /usr/share/man/man1/autopoint.1.gz
   engauge-digitizer-doc: /usr/share/doc/engauge-digitizer-doc/html/tutorautopointgraph.html
   [...more things...]
   ruby-ffi: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi/autopointer.rb
   ```

   So the package in this case seems to be `autopoint`.
5. In which repository is the package?

   ```
   apt-cache policy autopoint
   ```

   which says:

   ```
   autopoint:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3
     Version table:
        0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 0
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        0.18.3.1-1ubuntu2 0
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
   ```

So it is in `main`; no need to add more repository (it could be `/universe`, `/partner` etc. which you have to enable).

Comment: IMO `apt-cache search` is better than apt-file.. but I dunno.

Comment: @Seth `apt-cache search` searches the name and description of the packages, `apt-file search` searches the files too, even if not installed. In the case above,   `apt-cache search tutorautopointgraph.html` will not find anything, while `apt-file search tutorautopointgraph.html`will find the package èngauge-digitzer-doc`...

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point, because the OP was searching for a package.. Unless you're saying using apt-file will help since autopoint isn't in the 10.04 repos..

Comment: @Seth yes - in 10.04 the package is named "gettext". So `apt-cache search autopoint` will not find it (the word autopoint is not in the package name nor in the description). `apt-file` will find it, because it searches also in the list of files that a package will install... try to search which package provides `/bin/cat` ;-) (hint: `apt-file search -F /bin/cat`)